# Why is there no space whose dual is $C_\mathbb{R}[0,1]$?

Tags: functional-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$C_0(X)$ is not the dual of a complete normed space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210043/c-0x-is-not-the-dual-of-a-complete-normed-space)
>   [Is any Banach space a dual space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242034/is-any-banach-space-a-dual-space)

While studying for a course of functional analysis I read somewhere that there is no normed vector space $X$ with $X^*=C_\mathbb{R}[0,1]$. I also found what at first glance seems like a complete proof of this fact:

Assume there is such a space $X$, then by Alaoglu's theorem the closed unit ball $B^*$ in $X^*$ is weak* compact. The unique extremal points of $B^*$ are the constant functions $f(x) = \pm 1$, and their closed convex hull is not all of $B^*$. This is a contradiction to Krein-Milman's theorem.

Now, I have a problem with this proof: to apply Krein-Milman to a set you need it to be convex and compact *with respect to the topology induced by the norm*, at least according to how it is usually stated. My hypothesis is that actually you can apply it to sets which are only compact in the weak* topology. Is this true? How do you prove it?

Comment: It seems http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krein-Milman_theorem contains the usual statement of the Krein-Milman theorem, valid for compact convex sets in locally convex spaces. The proof is the same as the one you probably know: 1. Zorn's lemma shows that every extremal set contains a minimal extremal set. 2. Hahn-Banach shows that a minimal extremal set is reduced to a point, hence there are extremal points. 3. If the closed convex hull of the extremal points were not everything, there would have to be another extremal point.

Comment: You can look at this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242034/is-any-banach-space-a-dual-space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Krein-Milman is a theorem about locally convex topological vector spaces.  The weak and weak* topologies are topological vector spaces of this kind. To wit, you do not need norm compactness.

Comment: I know this is an old post but I have a question about this: from what I understand the Krein-Milman theorem asserts that the convex hull is wk*-dense, not norm-dense. So while the constant functions are not norm-dense in $C[0,1]$, they might be wk*-dense right? Hence I do not see a contradiction, since we do not know anything about the wk* topology.

Comment: A finite-dimensional subspace of any Hausdorff topological vector space is closed.  The constants are a 1-dimensional subspace, hence weak-\*closed, and clearly they are not all of $C([0,1])$, hence not weak-\* dense.